# Chrome Hosted apps no longer allowed?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I have (had) a hosted app in the Chrome Web Store, built using the following Developer documentation:

https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide

After being in the Chrome Web Store for years, I recently received an email saying my app does not comply:

> Your item did not comply with the following section of our policy:
>
> Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to install or
>   launch another app, theme, or extension. For example, if your app’s
>   primary function is to launch a desktop app that the user has already
>   installed, that is not allowed. **Another example is a packaged app that
>   just launches a website**.

My question is: Did the rules change? A Hosted App IS an app that launches a website. Does anyone know what to change in a Hosted App to make it compliant again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Hosted App, a Chrome App (successor to Packaged App), and a Chrome Extension are three separate things, distinguished by how their manifest.json file is set up. What this email appears to be saying is that you're not allowed to have a Chrome App (which they call a packaged app) whose only purpose is to launch another app or a web site. They are saying nothing about Hosted Apps, which continue to be allowed, as far as I know. (I have one in the Chrome Web Store myself.)

Is your app truly a Hosted App? Or, is it a (legacy) packaged app or a Chrome App?

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check... I had inadvertently uploaded an old packaged app manifest the last time I published.